# How to update a textview from a countdowntimer in android?

Tags: android, dialog, countdowntimer

When a user wins more than, say, 100 tokens, id like an image to pop up and count up the tokens and play some sounds. To add a little.. pizzazz. But however I try it, I either get a nullpointer, or the first number, no counting.

How can I accomplish this?

There's the method I have so far. Changed it around a bunch experimenting.

```
public void bonusPop(int mWinnings){

    final int count = 0;

    //token prize popup1
    final Dialog payDialog = new Dialog(GemSlotMachineActivity.this);
    payDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    payDialog.setContentView(R.layout.win_pop);
    payDialog.setCancelable(true);
    payDialog.show();

    new CountDownTimer(mWinnings * 50, 50) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){

            //count++;

            TextView winText = (TextView) payDialog.findViewById(R.id.winText);
            winText.setText(Float.toString(count));

        }

        public void onFinish() {

            finish();

        }

    }.start();

    };
```

}

Extra credit: The images background that shows in the dialog, behind the text, is transparent, because i want to see the slots behind this popup. But there is white on 3 sides of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to initiliaze this code:

```
TextView winText = (TextView) payDialog.findViewById(R.id.winText);
```

outside of your `CountDownTimer` and instead of `Float.toString(count)` use `String.valueOf(count)`. Also I saw that you use final in your `count` which is not ok since you increment it, just make it as global variable instead. I modified your code like below. try it if it works

```
int count = 0;

public void bonusPop(int mWinnings){
    final Dialog payDialog = new Dialog(GemSlotMachineActivity.this);
    payDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    payDialog.setContentView(R.layout.win_pop);
    payDialog.setCancelable(true);
    payDialog.show();
    TextView winText = (TextView) payDialog.findViewById(R.id.winText);

    new CountDownTimer(mWinnings * 50, 50) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
            count++;
            winText.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: It worked! You're awesome man. Only thing is it disappeared at 97, and im assuming that's because the last three when so fast you couldn't see them. But, how would I make it stall a moment after it hits the final number?

Comment: Never mind. All figured out. Now to tackle the transparency on the dialog thank again Rashid!

Comment: can you show your dialog so i can get what it looks like?